# Получить значения всех выбранных checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице динамически в цикле создаются чекбоксы:

```
<input id="CB'.$sql['id'].'" type="checkbox" name="active[]" value="'.$sql['id'].'">
```

Как получить при клике на кнопку значения (value) всех отмеченных чекбокс? Желательно в таком виде: value1, value2, value3

```js
$("#go-step-2").click(function() {
    var ids = $("input[name='active[]']").val();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  //создаём массив для значений флажков
  var checkboxes = [];
  $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
    //добавляем значение каждого флажка в этот массив
    checkboxes.push(this.value);
  });
  /*объединяем массив в строку с разделителем-запятой. Но лучше подобные вещи хранить в массиве. Для наглядности - вывод в консоль.*/
  console.log(checkboxes.join(','));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="value1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="value2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="value3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" value="value4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5" value="value5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6" value="value6" />

<button>Клик</button>
```

Comment: По моему чего-то не хватает)

Comment: @Haswell , вот я голова два уха. Проглядел. Благодарю.